# How can I ignore the fatal error from mongodb, prevent it break my long-time parsing task

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm importing billions of records , insert it to mongoDB.

After running about 10 hours, I got error 'Client Error: Remaining data too small for BSON object'.

And then the error broke my task,

I tried to use `try exception` to skip the buggy data, and keep going.

But it didn't work too.(the exception still breaks the parsing task)

So I wonder how to let mongoDB don't break my script, even some errors occurs, just ignore it and keep going.

```
  def bulk_insert_to_collection(collection_name)
    model = collection_name.capitalize.constantize.new
    begin
      model.collection.insert(@data_in_chunk)
    rescue Exception => e
      # ignore it
    end
  end
```

Comment: How are you importing the data and what `didn't work` mean?

Comment: because I am not familiar with mongoid, I will ask a couple of questions here. Are you using [bulk insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) in your client code? If so is it ordered/unordered? Also why are not you using normal mongorestore utility?

Comment: HI @SalvadorDali because I need to parse the raw date and use ruby to decode the raw data, then convert it into Hash/dictionary object, and bulk insert later. because there are billions of data, it's in-efficient insert one by one

Comment: Silly question/suggestion , but you check for empty data before save it? Recently I got this error and the solution was avoid an empty collection before save (with if !@data_in_chunk.blank?)

Answer (score 0):

Put your batch insert inside of a loop so that when one batch fails you can just move on to the next one. You should only insert 1000 at a time anyway because [that is what mongo supports](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/). This allows you had to handle failures however you want to without losing insert performance.

Comment: you didn't answer the question. the exception will break the routine. even the try -catch still could not by-pass the exception.